# Strange hint alignment in the Advanced Search Tips

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, tooltips

For many of items in the Advanced Search Tips section you can see curious indent for the second line:

[image: 2nd-indent]

Does it make some sense?

[Related question in ruSO.Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4009/176217)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be fixed momentarily. The joys of whitespace in html sometimes mattering and sometimes not.