# Improve formatting for Top Tags tooltip

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, tooltips, information-display

Tooltip in the Top Tags section of the user profile shows an information about questions and answers posted by user. Currently it looks like this:

> [image: now]

My request is to split sentences into different lines. In this case result would be looked like this:

> [image: request]

Comment: The ordinary tooltip (HTML title attribute) does not support new lines. Some browsers do support, but only as a "bonus", not all browsers have it so it's useless. So to achieve that, SE will have to switch to a custom tooltip, e.g. the one used for impact. (hence this feature is more complicated to do than what it looks like on first sight)

Comment: @ShadowWizard some tooltips already [support multiline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286555/339911).

Comment: Not for all browsers, e.g. I think Firefox still does not support it. (so you'll see it all in one line there)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I use FF, and I see multiline in both cases. I got second picture by modifing html source of the user profile page.

Comment: For wide support,  `title` attribute should contain xml entities like `&#0010;`  instead of raw `\n`

Comment: @ShadowWizard multiline tooltips also work on [candidate block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Gkd.png) for [moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1).