# No tooltips for Advanced Search Tips

Tags: support, bug, search, tooltips

Two years ago there were tooltips for the [Advanced Search Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search) (see related post: [Strange hint alignment in the Advanced Search Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286555/339911)), but nowadays there are no tooltips. What's the reason to remove them?

Comment: More likely oversight when making some unrelated change.